# Disable "Changed Items" Highlight on SharePoint 2007 User Profile Public Page

Tags: user-profile

How can I disable "Changed Items" Highlight (Yellow) on Share Point 2007 User Profile Public Page?

When someone change some property in his profile, other users visiting his public page see that value highlighted with yellow. Can I disable this??

Thanks,
Darko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlight will only be displayed when the querystring contains 'highlight=' as far as I know.

You could possibly add some javascript to the Person.aspx page that will redirect the browser if the querystring contains this value.